# How do I iterate multiple List<WebElement> in selenium /Java

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following WebElement List in a page

```
@FindBy(xpath="a")

private List<WebElement> generalList ;

@FindBy(xpath="b")

private List<WebElement> eventList ;

@FindBy(xpath="c")

private List<WebElement> additionalList ;
```

I want to iterate each of the above list items and apply clear through a loop instead of writing the following way which currently works

```
for(WebElement type:generalList)
type.clear();
for(WebElement type:eventList)
type.clear();
for(WebElement type:additionalList)
type.clear();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java 8 you can try using [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) as below :-

```
generalList.stream().forEach(elem -> elem.clear());

eventList.stream().forEach(elem -> elem.clear());

additionalList.stream().forEach(elem -> elem.clear());
```

Or concatenate all of these list and try as :

```
Stream.of(generalList, eventList, additionalList).flatMap(Collection::stream).forEach(elem -> elem.clear());
```

Comment: Dont worry about it. I have been down voted in core java questions for using Java 8 features. Guessing some folks aint like introduction of functional programming in Java

Comment: I have not down voted you. It meets exactly what the person asked. I just mentioned some people just do not like answers with Java 8 features.

Comment: I downvoted your original answer because it completely ignored OP's intent of avoiding duplicate statements.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I try to point out mistakes or misunderstandings, but it seemed like you just disregarded the question to push your lambdas...

Comment: If I want to Add something instead of clearing how can I do that.   String [] name={"lastName","firstName"};

Comment: I'm sorry but you need to ask another question regarding this please...:)

Answer (score 0):

With Guava:

```
for (WebElement type : Iterables.concat(generalList, eventList, additionalList)) {
    type.clear();
}
```

With Java 8:

```
Stream.of(generalList, eventList, additionalList)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .forEach(WebElement::clear);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a helper function

```
void clearAll(List<WebElement>... f) {
        Arrays.stream(f).forEach((li)->{li.forEach(WebElement::clear);});
}
```

and call it like `clearAll(generalList, eventList, additionalList);`